# General questions regarding MVVM pattern with WCF service

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf, mvvm

I'm bulding my first WPF application using the MVVM pattern over a WCF Service. I'm new on this technologies. After a lot of work and with the help of this comunity, I manage to create the bases for my app, from data and service layers to a full client using MVVM pattern and WPF. Still, got some conceptual concern/doubts about this technics that maybe someone can help clarify.

**MY QUESTIONS**

> 1) As long as I undestand each view-viewmodel has not knowledge of the
>   exitance of the rest of the views. That means that each view with his
>   viewmodel is isolated. So what happends when in my app i need for
>   instance to show a view, that creates a new view and need to get the
>   result from this child view on the caller view? In this case each view
>   has is viewmodel, so how do i share this information between
>   views/viewmodels?
>
> 2) My WCF service expose POCO's object to Client. So this is
>   essentialy a disconected enviroment. So what about reports? If i
>   follow MVVM guidelines, i should contact my WCF service from my
>   viewmodel, get the objects and then expose a property that i somehow
>   had to bind to a report object in XAML, right? So the report should
>   has not know about my database.Which objects can i use to build my
>   reports that allow me to use POCO's object a data origin?
>
> 3) This one I know is a bit controversial in the comunity. My Data and
>   Service layer comunicate data using POCO's generated from the
>   database, wich is ok. Now my doubt is, when i comunicate to client,
>   should i use this same objects or build my own custom objects?
>
> 4)When i need to save a header-detail object to database (for instance
>   a purchase order from clients), should i create a custom object wich
>   has an instance of the header object an a collection of detail items
>   on server side, or this is viewmodel work?
>
> 5) Can someone give me a practical example of when is usefull to have more than one view per viewmodel? From what I have been doing i get to the conclusion that every view extremely depends on the viewmodel,

Any comment will be appreciated. I'm trying to follow good programing
practices here.

**UPDATE**

After the revived comments i'll try to clarify my questions:

> About 1) I had suspected that this is one of the key issues with MVVM. Anyway i'm trying to stay away form external tools, because in the past i had severe issues about then. When you did encounter problems with external toolkits finding an answer is very hard or sometimes impossible. Can't this be resolved with a not so complex approach using basic MVVM that comes in Visual Studio?
>
> About 2) I'm not using anything yet. I'm thinking in advance. How do you recommend to build my reports in a MVVM way? In the past, i had done something similar using disconnected Crystal reports objects. I made the query in the server (with a recordset), send the data to client using XML or something, and in the client tranform the data to recordset again and set the report datasource to this object. I'm thinking in a similar approach but using pocos classes and MVVM. Any ideas?
>
> About 3) I think this is what i've been doing, but i'm not sure. For instance when i need to fill a combobox with customers for filter customers orders, I expose directly my POCOs classes. I know this is not the more efficient approach because i need to transfer all the propertis of my objecs when I need only 2 o 3 of them, but for simplicity i send the entire object. When i need to show in a grid the result filteres customers orders,I use a custom class with only the propertis that i want to show in the grid. When you said "i Create DTO" you mean this? Isn't POCO's classes also DTO?
>
> About 4) When I need to insert or update a master detail object (a customer puchase order for instead), it generaly involves making changes to at least 2 or more database objects. So my question is: Should I create and expose a complex object in the datalayer that contains individual database object classes? or is better to expose the base object and let viewmodel handle the individual object and send them one by one to service layer for update? Hope it gets clear.
>
> About 5) I suspect that. I'll keep it in mind.
>   Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. This is an inherent problem with MVVM in WPF.  There are two libraries that help to solve this problem.  Take a look at
>      Caliburn.Micro which uses a ViewModel first approach to solve this
>      problem.  The other library is Microsoft's own Prism library.  this
>      library takes a View first approach to solve this issue.
> 2. how are you generating reports?  If you are using something like SSRS, they have their own exposed WCF service for retrieving reports. 
>      You can wrap this in a service and consume it in your ViewModels.
> 3. It depends.  How complex are your objects?  if you are doing simple operations the data model is probably fine.  However, for more
>      complex operations i tend to create a DTO (data transfer oject) that
>      encompasses a Unit of Work.
> 4. I'm not sure i understand the question.
> 5. You should strive to always have one view per viewmodel. If there is a reason to have a separate view, there is probably a good reason
>      to have a separate viewmodel.  The problem you are probably having is
>      related to #1 and you want to somehow share data between these views.

Overall,  I know your pain and I have a love/hate relationship with WPF using MVVM for some of the reasons that you have stated.  out of the two frameworks that I list in #1, I have used Calibrun.micro and it makes WPF MVVM much more accessible and easy to use.  a good blog post to get started is:

http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/

If you want you can also take a look at prism:

http://compositewpf.codeplex.com/

There are some other ones out there. These are the two that i have had experience with.  Prism is OK. However, I personally do not like their navigation service.

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your great answer! I edit my question to add more details. If you can, please take a look at it.