# Bind all Tab item view model at start in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have an application with 2 tabs which are *Person* and *User Management* in WPF with MVVM. Now the problem is when I click on *Person Mag tab*, the *PersonViewModel* will bind to *Person Mag View*, and *User Mag* same as mentioned situation also.

How to make *Person* and *User Mag tab* bind its view model at start of the application (both bind viewmodel for its own view at the same time) instead of bind the view model when I clicked on that tab.

[image]

**XAML**

```
 <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5">
        <TabItem Width="190" Margin="1">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Images/Person-Management-Icon.png" Width="32" Height="32" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Person Mangement" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ptab:PersonManagementView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
        <TabItem Margin="1">
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Images/User-Management-Icon.png" Width="32" Height="32" />
                    <TextBlock Text="User Mangement" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <TabItem.ContentTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ptab:UserManagementView />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabItem.ContentTemplate>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</DockPanel>
```

PersonManagement XAML

```
<!--View Model Section-->
<UserControl.DataContext>
    <vm:PersonViewModel />
</UserControl.DataContext>
<!--End View Model Section-->

<!--Resources Section-->
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="../Resources/ResourceDictionary.xaml" />
</UserControl.Resources>
<!--End Resources Section-->

<DockPanel Name="Person_Management_View">
    <TabControl DockPanel.Dock="Top">
        <TabItem>
            <TabItem.Header>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Images/Person-Creation-Icon.png" Width="24" Height="24" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Person Creation" Margin="5,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                </StackPanel>
            </TabItem.Header>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <!--Name-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <!--Gender-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <!--Department-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    <!--Error Message-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="25" />
                    <!--Save Button-->
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <!--Name Section-->
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Name"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content=":"/>
                <TextBox Name="txtPersonName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2"  Margin="4">
                    <TextBox.Text>
                        <Binding Path="PersonObject.Name" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" >
                            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                                <r:PersonNameRule ValidatesOnTargetUpdated="True" />
                            </Binding.ValidationRules>
                        </Binding>
                    </TextBox.Text>
                </TextBox>
                <!--End Name Section-->

                <!--Gender Section-->
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Gender"/>
                <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Content=":"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2"  Margin="4"  ItemsSource="{Binding GenderList}" SelectedItem="{Binding PersonObject.Gender}"/>
                <!--End Gender Section-->

                <!--Department Section-->
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="Department" />
                <Label Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Content=":"/>
                <ComboBox Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" Margin="4" ItemsSource="{Binding DepartmentList}" SelectedItem="{Binding PersonObject.DepartmentName}" />
                <!--End Department Section-->

                <!--Error Message Section-->
                <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="2" Margin="4,4,4,0" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=txtPersonName, Path=(Validation.Errors), Converter={StaticResource toVisibilityConverter}}" Style="{StaticResource RedTextBlock}">
                    <TextBlock.Text>
                        <Binding ElementName="txtPersonName" Path="(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent"/>
                    </TextBlock.Text>
                </TextBlock>
                <!--End Error Message Section-->

                <!--Save Button Section-->
                <Button Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="2"  HorizontalAlignment="Right" MinWidth="100" Margin="4,0,4,4" Content="Save" Command="{Binding CreatePersonCommand}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="false" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=txtPersonName, Path=(Validation.HasError)}" Value="false" />
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="true" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
                <!--End Save Button Section-->

            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>

    <!--Person Data Section-->
    <DataGrid Name="PersonDataGrid" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*" ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id" Binding="{Binding PersonID}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Gender" Binding="{Binding Gender, Converter={StaticResource emptyStringConverter}}" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Department" Binding="{Binding DepartmentName, Converter={StaticResource emptyStringConverter}}" />
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button IsEnabled="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource oppositeBoolConverter}}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DeletePersonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding PersonID}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
                            <Image Source="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource deleteImageConverter}}" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.ViewPersonCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" CommandParameter="{Binding PersonID}" Style="{StaticResource TransparentButton}">
                            <Image Source="/Images/Update-Icon.png" Width="16" Height="16"/>
                        </Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
    <!--End Person Data Section-->

</DockPanel>
```

Comment: Post the code where you bind the data

Comment: @user1219310 Hi,pls let us know,why should u need to load person viewmodel when your on UserManagement Tab. [Navigation through Views](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22793164/wpf-navigate-throug-views-using-mvvm-pattern)

Comment: @Sajeetharan the XAML code that was I used for binding

Comment: @Eldho erm, because I have a clipboard function, will copy Person and User details when I click the Copy to Clipboard button.

Comment: Thus, I need Person and User tab both of them bind they own viewmodel when the application at first launch

Answer (score 0):

Try this

> Add Loaded event to TabControl

```
<TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left" DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="5" Loaded="Tab_OnLoaded" >
```

> Remove the ContentTemplate from xaml and assign content in code like

```
    void Tab_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var tabControl = sender as TabControl;
        if (tabControl != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < tabControl.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                if (i == 1)
                    (tabControl.Items[i] as TabItem).Content = new UserControl2();//Here assign the Usercontrol that you want to set as Content
            }
            tabControl.Loaded -= Tab_OnLoaded; // Do this on first time only
        }
    }
```

I dont think its a good approach . I hope this will help.